# Sample data of quarterly (annualized) real GDP growth

Tags: data, market-data, macro-economics

I am looking for a database that provides me the quarterly (annualized) real GDP growth (quarter t and t-1) of US, Germany and England.

For the US data i went here:

https://www.philadelphiafed.org/research-and-data/real-time-center/real-time-data/data-files/routput

is the first file: "**Vintages 1965:Q4 to present**" ??

For Germany and England i couldn't find.

Any help?

Thanks.